# Is there a way to compare two Java war files

Tags: java

We built some war files for our web server a while back and have now rebuilt them.

To ensure that nothing has changed (and as a quality check), we tried to compare them using WinMerge. The differences we can see look like they are due to some kind of meta data e.g. the files being built on different dates?

The difference in the lines seems to be consistent e.g.

> «d}<

and

> ³Ze<

The war files are still both the same size.

Is there a way to compare them that strips out the meta data such as date?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WAR files are basically Zip files. Why not extract the contents and compare each file in turn? This avoids any meta-data that is a part of the WAR file. You can also figure out what the differences actually are if any are discovered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88216/finding-differences-between-versions-of-a-java-class-file might be helpful after unzipping

Comment: Two good answers - this one was first (7 seconds earlier) so this one accepted.

Answer (score 10):

I generally use an approach like this and run 2 unzip commands and diff the output as required. For example I need to compare 2 Java WAR files.

```
$ sdiff --width 160 \
   <(unzip -l -v my_num1.war | cut -c 1-9,59-,49-57 | sort -k3) \
   <(unzip -l -v my_num2.war | cut -c 1-9,59-,49-57 | sort -k3)
```

Resulting in output like so:

```
--------          -------                                                       --------          -------
Archive:                                                                        Archive:
-------- -------- ----                                                          -------- -------- ----
48619281          130 files                                                   | 51043693          130 files
    1116 060ccc56 index.jsp                                                         1116 060ccc56 index.jsp
       0 00000000 META-INF/                                                            0 00000000 META-INF/
     155 b50f41aa META-INF/MANIFEST.MF                                        |      155 701f1623 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 Length   CRC-32  Name                                                           Length   CRC-32  Name
    1179 b42096f1 version.jsp                                                       1179 b42096f1 version.jsp
       0 00000000 WEB-INF/                                                             0 00000000 WEB-INF/
       0 00000000 WEB-INF/classes/                                                     0 00000000 WEB-INF/classes/
       0 00000000 WEB-INF/classes/com/                                                 0 00000000 WEB-INF/classes/com/
...
...
```

I prefer this approach since it doesn't require space to uncompress the files and then compare them.

Comment: what is the significance of `cut -c 1-9,59-,49-57` here?

Comment: @AjayKumar - I'm parsing the output from the `unzip` command selectively taking certain character ranges from it. Look here for an example of what a WAR file looks like when you unzip it - https://www.baeldung.com/linux/extract-war.

Answer (score 8):

It should be easier if you unzip them first and then compare folders.

In Windows you could just use the 'jar' executable which comes with the jdk

```
jar -xvf xxxx.war
```

Then you can use WinMerge to compare the 2 folders.

Hope this helps

Comment: WinMerge for the win!

Answer (score 6):

you can use eclipse to compare jar/war files.
http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91839415.html

The link does not mention war file. I'm using Indigo, it seems eclipse only support jar comparison hence I have to rename the war extension to jar to get eclipse to do the structural comparison.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `pkgdiff`:

```
pkgdiff a.war b.war
```

Readily available in Linux, fairly parsable output (you can also check the status code from a bash script). It also generates an awesome HTML report.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Beyond Compare" free trial... (or buy it)
I think it is the only tool that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure WinMerge to compare zip files (and by the way, .WAR files), if you install the 7zip plugin of WinMerge.
Keep in mind that is not very easy to install, you must install the plugin, it is made of .dll and must be extracted in a folder.... Honestly I dont remember how I did it.
I believed at the end I used the standalone installer ooption and use 9.20 version of the plugin.

Althoug some times, winmerge tells me there are diferences in .class files, it hightlighs the binary line, but i dont see anydiference.
At least you can compare war folder structure at least.